How to force a dataset refresh in MS Power Automate
I’m using MS Power Automate to automate some document creation tasks for rows in an Excel online  spreadsheet. I have the users update a status column (which has dropdown type data validation on it) in the row and manually run the flow when a document needs to be created for the row. I have the flow using the Excel for Business data source and a filter on the list rows function to limit rows returned.
The problem is that there is a lag of 1-2 minutes between the update of the status column and when the Power Automate flow can identify changes in the status column. I’d like to force a refresh of the Excel sheet source to eliminate the delay / cached values but cannot figure out how to do this.
I’ve tried modifying the flow to add a row, delete a row, list worksheets, get tables, etc but it’s not worked.

your question is not clear. Is the workflow not starting in the expected time frame? or is the data changing while the workflow is running, but the workflow can't see the change? What is the workflow trigger? What actions are you using that don't give you the desired data? Please give more details about the steps that are not delivering the result or acting in the time frame you need. As it is, your question can't really be answered, because nobody can tell where the problem might be.
